# how to request UserHostAddress?

Tags: java, web-services

i am converting .net web service to java web service in which the code as follows :

String Strresp=dataprocessing.SaveToDB(argdata,this.Context.Request.UserHostAddress);

how to call User Host Address in java can any one tell me.

Comment: what are you using on the Java side? Servlets?

Comment: no Web Serive as Jax-Ws in netbeans 6.9

Answer (score 1):

From the `HttpServletRequest` you can use this method

```
getRemoteHost()
```

to get the IP address of the user.